# Issue with NextJS navigation

Tags: next.js

I am getting the following error when I navigate to Gallery and Contact Link, except when I click on home link ('/').

```
head-manager.js:2 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
    at head-manager.js:2
```

Below is my header.js component:

```
import Link from 'next/link'

import { COLORS, FONT_SIZE } from '../theme/constants'

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <Link href='/'>
        <a className='site-name'>Name</a>
      </Link>
      <nav>
        <Link href='/'>
          <a>Home</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href='/gallery'>
          <a>Gallery</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href='/contact'>
          <a>Contact</a>
        </Link>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I am using getStaticProps to fetch data from sitedata.json in index.js file and passing contents of file as props through Layout component. Thats how my header and Head components receive site title and description info. But I am not passing them through the Gallery and About page files. I figured if I get them once from index file it would be able to use them globally, but that is not the case. I have to fetch that data using getStaticProps on every page file, which got rid of error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is in the above component, but possibly in your `_document.js`, `_app.js`, or relevant page that is trying to update `title`, or other Head properties. You will see this error if the property you are using to set the value does not exist:

if `props.myUndefinedProperty` does not exist below, you will see the:

```
head-manager.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
```

```
import Head from 'next/head';
...
return (
  ...
  <Head>
     <title>{props.myUndefinedProperty}</title>
  </Head>
```

Comment: I just double checked and I can still see the title I want showing up in tab. I initially had my layout component include the Head element for my title, and other meta tags, but then after running it through lighthouse it mentioned to include ```<html lang='en'/>``` so I made the _document.js file to include it, unless I can include it in next/head element as well? you can take take a look at the repo here https://github.com/jgil-r/website-aa